# Loading a non-materialised array from Postgres in Java

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc

**The setting:**
I am connecting to a Postgres database with Java, and trying to load the `pg_stats.histogram_bounds` statistic, which is an array in Postgres. I can extract the field as a `sql.Array` object with `Array histogramBounds = rs.getArray("histogram_bounds");`. This object can be printed with `toString()`, but I can't otherwise access any of the data (e.g. calls to `histogramBounds.getArray()`, `getBaseType`, etc.) all generate `PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.`.

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html), as well as various tutorials and SE questions suggest this should be valid.

Apparently `sql.Array` objects do not hold the array data directly, but point to it on the server. From my experiments I have the following MWE which shows the difference between an array value stored in a table in Postgres, and one which is somehow ephemeral or non-materialised (as I suspect `pg_stats` may be, being a view onto other internal tables).

**The MWE:**
I have two queries, one which selects data form a table and works, and one which selects data directly from the query, and does not work. I can't see any reason in the documentation they should not both work, and I would like to get the second version working to get the Java array `[1, 2, 3]`.
Confusingly, `toString` still displays the data correctly in the second case, so it must be loaded successfully at some point.

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PostgresStatsExperiments {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/tmp", "admin", "admin");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name, my_data from array_test;"); // This one works
        //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT '{1, 2, 3}' AS my_data;"); // This one does not work.

        while (rs.next()) {
            Array myData = rs.getArray("my_data");
            System.out.println(myData);
            System.out.println(myData.getArray()); // PSQLException here in the second case
        }

        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

The table `array_test` looks like this:

```
create table array_test ( name varchar, my_data integer ARRAY[3] );
insert into array_test values ('Alice', '{1, 2, 3}');
insert into array_test values ('Bob', '{4, 5, 6}');
```

In the second case, I get the following output:

```
{1, 2, 3}
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TypeInfoCache.getPGArrayElement(TypeInfoCache.java:425)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.buildArray(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:540)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.getArrayImpl(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:171)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.getArray(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:128)
    at tmp.PostgresStatsExperiments.main(PostgresStatsExperiments.java:21)
```

I am using `postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar` from Maven, and the problem is also the same with the latest `42.2.4.jre7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the query `SELECT '{1, 2, 3}' AS my_data` the column `my_data` is **not** any array. It's a string that happens to *look* like an array - but the single quotes denote a `text` (or `varchar`) value.

And because the column's data type is not an array, calling `getArray()` throws an exception.

If you want an array, you need to cast the text value to an array:

```
SELECT '{1, 2, 3}'::int[] AS my_data;
```

or better: use an explicit array constructor:

```
SELECT array[1, 2, 3] AS my_data;
```

---

`pg_stats.histogram_bounds` is defined as `anyarray` - it's not a typed array as it contains different data types for each column (which means in each row, as that table contains one row per table column).

Apparently the JDBC driver can't work with `anyarray` properly.

To deal with the values from Java code, I think the easiest way is to convert it to a string which then can be converted back to a text array (as the string representation is correct).

So if you use the following query:

```
select schemaname, tablename, attname, histogram_bounds::text::text[] as histogram_bounds, ..
from pg_stats
where ...
```

You should be able to retrieve the content of the `histogram_bounds` column (but you get everything as strings, rather than a data type matching the column's data type).

Comment: Thanks. "my_data is not any array. It's a string that happens to look like an array" - This seems extremely obvious now that you point it out; oops. Maybe I was tricked by the call to rs.getArray() working correctly, which I would not intuitively expect. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I had suspected `anyarray` may cause an issue, which was the reason I wanted to build a simpler MWE first as an experiment. I'm surprised I didn't try one of the single-typed array fields from `pg_data` first, but I guess I must have skipped that step. If I convert everything to strings, I can always pull the SQL type from `pg_data` as well to help with the decoding on the Java side.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too. There was a int8[] type of column in my table.

I moved my table to another schema with the DataGrip program. When the program moved my table to another schema, I saw that it changed its type of column to "text".

When I changed to int8[] type, resolved my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).